# Saving and loading files in HTML5 with LibGDX

Tags: html, load, libgdx, save

I was looking at the "wiki" for LibGDX and I don't see a method to save or load when using HTML5. 
Could anyone point me in the right direction on how I can go about saving and loading files in HTML5 via LibGDX?

I know it is possible with HTML5 just not sure how to do it through LibGDX.

Comment: How about checking the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [File handling wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) says, that on HTML5 only `Gdx.Files.internal` is available.
`Gdx.Files.internal` is read only, so you can only load data from there.
there is one other possibility: The [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences).
The wiki says:

> Preferences are also the only way to date to write persistent data when your application is run in the browser.

This means, that only this way you can sava **and** load data.